# Peer to Peer chat using C#/ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, chat

I've been all over Google looking for a viable Peer-to-Peer chat to add to a website, it would be great if you could add some bells and whistles like sending images and such but at the very least I need to be able to click on a "Chat" button on a user's page and have it open a popup window where you can initiate a chat with that user.

Are there any tutorials out there for something like this?  Can anyone suggest a good starting point?

Comment: Have you looked at SignalR?

Comment: A little, but can't find a decent tutorial/demo.  I've seen a few that use a full tab, none at all that use a pop-up window.